# ng-bind-html directive not displaying "0" when data is getting comes from ASYNC function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div ng-bind-html="retrievedData.summary.classAvgGrade"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var data = {
  summary:{
  classAvgGrade:0,//10 (change by yourself)
  student:12
  }
}

angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('foo', function($scope, $interval) {
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.retrievedData = data;
    }, 1000);
  });

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/tbutbap3/16/)

NOTE:

1. If I use `ng-bind` instead of `ng-bind-html` it will work;
2. Otherwise we can define (declare) the object before async call made

   ```
   $scope. retrievedData= {
     summary:{
         classAvgGrade:0
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem appending a `.toString()` to the variable. So, rather than

```
<div ng-bind-html="retrievedData.summary.classAvgGrade"></div>
```

Try

```
<div ng-bind-html="retrievedData.summary.classAvgGrade.toString()"></div>
```